# Copy ssh-id from remote host to another with Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cloud, ansible, ssh-keys

I am running Ansible 2.0 on my local computer. I have 3 ubuntu servers on the cloud which I am provisioning from my local. 1 Master, 2 Slaves.

**I need to copy to the master's ssh id to the slaves in Ansible.**

I checked the authorize module but as far as I understand, I can copy my id to the remotes. However what I need is copy one remote's ssh id to the others.

**Is there any way to do that in Ansible?**

First thing that came to my mind is to copy the master's id to local then copy from local to the slaves.. But I wanna believe that there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Synchronize](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html) module to copy files between hosts. Make sure **mode** is set to **push**.

```
- hosts: slave
  tasks:    
   - name: Copy from master to slave
     synchronize: src=<path_to_file_in_master> dest=<path_to_file_in_slave> mode=push 
     delegate_to: master
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  It does work! I had to add the line "remote_user: root" as additional.